# Unable to recover deleted file using icat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, file-recovery

I am trying to recover a deleted file using icat, but I don't get any output.

The partition looks like this

```
$ fls -o 59472 -r w3_image.dd
d/d 11: lost+found
r/r 12: msg
r/r * 13:   msg.txt
d/d 2529:   $OrphanFiles
```

I am able to read data from a non deleted file using

```
$ icat -r -o 59472 w3_image.dd 12
```

This is just some binary data. But I am unable to read from inode 13.

```
$ icat -r -o 59472 w3_image.dd 13
```

I am pretty sure I should be able to recover this file, as it is a school exercise.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Don't you need the word `image` before w3_image.dd ?

Comment: Nope, if I add it, it says there is no such file or directory.